# Jquery issue, have to double click for the toggle to occur, can you tell me why?

Tags: php, jquery

All else is working fine

jQuery:

```
$(".edit").click(function()
{
    var user_id=$(this).attr('id');

     var options = '';
        $.getJSON("do_find_courses.php",{user_id:user_id}, function(data){
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              if(data[i].optionDisplay=="No File Categories")
              {
                  options = '<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">No products</option>';

              }
              else
              {
                  options +=' <input name="' + data[i].optionValue + '" type="checkbox" value="' + data[i].optionDisplay + '" />'+ data[i].optionDisplay +'<br>';

            //options += '<option value="' + data[i].optionValue + '">' + data[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';

              }

          }
          $("#chkbox"+user_id).slideToggle( "slow" ).html(options);
          //$("#chkbox"+user_id).html(options);


        });
     return false;


 });
```

php code generated for the a href

```
 <?php
                            $get_students=mysql_query("SELECT user_id ,surname,name, admin FROM users WHERE users.admin=0 ORDER BY users.surname ASC") or die(mysql_error());
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($get_students))
                        {
                            echo'       
                            <tr>

                                <td><h3>'.$row['surname'].'</h3></td>
                                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                                <td><div id="chkbox'.$row['user_id'].'"></div></td>
                                <td><a href="'.$row['surname'].','.$row['name'].'" class="ico del" id="'.$row['user_id'].'">Delete</a>
                                <a href="edit" id="'.$row['user_id'].'" class="ico edit">Edit</a></td>                          
                            </tr>';}
                ?>
```

Comment: Did you try to put your toggle outside getJson?

Comment: slide toggle work when your div in which you want to apply the slide toggle should be outside the click button on which slide toggle apply. You can see the help on http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8LXY6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $(".edit").unbind('click');
    $(".edit").click(function(){ bla bla bla});
});
```

Comment: and i think, your request is too long, just click once and wait

Comment: I tried the above, but same issue. On first click it displays the <div> as blank, only on the second click it displays the result

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: var user_id=$(this).attr('id');
$(this).click(); // write this string and try :D